# How to create layout for registration mobile number

Tags: android

http://snag.gy/0kz5e.jpg please look this Image I have to create layout but 
I am unable to do this there is some Problem with android control set on particular.

I am able to display controls in android:gravity bottom but my controls is not fix like image please check what I am missing where am doing wrong .
here is my Xml file code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/registraionimage" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="49dp"
            android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="94dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="Code" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="Phone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#0066FF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just try below code, I replace FrameLayout to RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="94dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="Code" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="Phone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#0066FF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanx @RobinHood really u great working fine if u don't mind can i have ur email id plz?

Comment: But image is not visible when i run it background image is not showing only android xml file it showing

Comment: Image is not displaying in back ground it displaying black

Comment: did u check @RobinHood?

Comment: what is bg03? can you send me? same xml working well from my side.

Comment: its is image bg03 name background image

Comment: u send please XMl i will check again

Comment: i will check on device ok

Comment: Spinner is not looking

Comment: But Spinner is not displaying